# Combinations/probability calculations using ball/bag analogy

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

I'm wondering how to approach this question? I'm analysing data for a research project, but I feel like it falls into the category of choosing combinations of balls in a bag. Any help would be much appreciated.

So - say I have 5 types (A-E) of balls, with a total of 457 in a bag
A - 127;
B - 100;
C - 61;
D - 52;
E - 117;

In a simple approach, each handful of balls I choose contains 4 balls, of some combination (a type of ball can only be repeated up to twice; ie. AABC can happen, but AAAC cannot).

1) How would I find the probability of grabbing, say, ABCE? ABCD? ABEE?

2) Now, to complicate things a bit, each handful can contain 4 OR 5 balls. What do I do now?

3) If I know test 101 handfuls, and find that A is grabbed twice (eg AAXX or AAXXX) 17 times, how can I see if that is statistically significant?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: By what *mechanism* do we ensure that "AAAC" cannot happen? If we pick (without replacement) $4$ times, it certainly can happen. If we happen to get for example the sequence ACAA, do we just put the balls back in the urn and try again?

Comment: Since I'm analysing research data, instead of actual balls in a bag, I have the parameter that the data I'm working with cannot occur more than twice in a single handful. I'm not sure how to frame that in terms of a ball-in-bag analogy

Comment: I should also add that order does not matter

Comment: It seemed clear that order does not matter. However, considering ordered selections can be useful in computing the probability of unordered results.

Comment: Okay, good to know.  As far as mechanisms go then, I feel like it's safe to assume that a combination of more that 2 repeats is just put back in the bag (not considered to be a trial) and another handful is grabbed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that if there are more than $2$ of a given type, then the items are replaced and we draw again. Imagine that each ball has a student number, so they are all distinguishable.   Then all "legal" selections  of $4$ balls are equally likely.

We need to count the legal selections, and for any pattern, count the "favourables" that yield that pattern.

Counting the legal selections is messy. There are $\binom{457}{4}$ choices with **no** restrictions.  We remove the bad ones. There are two types of bad: (i) all of the same type and (iii) $3$ of one type, and $1$ of another.

For (i), the number is $\binom{127}{4}+\binom{100}{4}+\cdots$.

For (ii), consider for example $3$ of Type A and $1$ of Type B. The $3$ Type A can be chosen in $\binom{127}{3}$ ways, the type B in $\binom{100}{1}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{127}{3}\binom{100}{1}$. There are nine other similar terms.

So assume now we have our count. We now count favourables.

The easiest to count is a pattern like ABCD. the number is $\binom{127}{1}\binom{100}{1}\binom{61}{1}\binom{52}{1}$.

For the pattern AABC, we use $\binom{127}{2}\binom{100}{1}\binom{61}{1}$.

The remaining type of pattern is exemplified by AABB. The number of favourables is $\binom{127}{2}\binom{100}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Just to clarify, to find the total legal possibilities, would it be (457,4)-[(127,4)+(100,4)+...+(127,3)(100,1)+(127,3)(61,1)+...+(117,3)(52,1)]?

Comment: There are $\dots$, so I cannot check. We subtract $5$ terms of the shape $\binom{k}{4}$, and a total of $10$ terms of the shape $\binom{k}{3}\binom{l}{1}$. Regrettably, because the $5$ different numbers you gave for A, B, C, D, E have no "structure," one cannot simplify the computation in any truly useful way.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to get a handle on the sample space. Let's start with the simple case first.

Assume we are grabbing 4 things from 5 piles with no more than 2 things from any one pile. So we are basically asking how many different ways can this happen. We can partition 4 in five different ways: $4, 3+1, 2+2, 2+1+1,$ and $1+1+1+1$. Since we aren't allowed to grab more than 2 from a pile, we can rule out the first two partitions. This leaves us with $2+2, 2+1+1,$ and $1+1+1+1$ as possible ways to pick from a pile.

There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to pick 2 from one pile and 2 from another pile.

There are $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}=30$ ways to pick 2 from one pile, 1 from another pile, and 1 more from yet a different pile.

There are $\binom{5}{4}=5$ ways to pick 1 from each pile.

So altogether you have $10+30+5=45$ ways to select any combination from the piles and so the probability is $\dfrac{1}{45}$.

For your more complicated answer for when you can have 4 or 5 balls, you need to repeat this kind analysis by considering how to partition 5.

Answer (score 0):

With a computer algebra system, it can be done easily using generating functions.

For the condition that at most 2 balls of each can be picked, the g.f. is:

$$\displaystyle G(x)=\left(1+127\, x+\binom{127}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+100\, x+\binom{100}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+61\, x+\binom{61}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+52\, x+\binom{52}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+117\, x+\binom{117}{2}\, x^2 \right)$$

The probability of choosing 4 balls with that condition is:

$$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(\text{4 balls})=\dfrac{[x^4]G(x)}{\dbinom{457}{4}}=\dfrac{1491797785}{\dbinom{457}{4}}\approx 0.831711884874402$$

The probability of choosing 5 balls with that condition is:

$$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(\text{5 balls})=\dfrac{[x^5]G(x)}{\dbinom{457}{5}}=\dfrac{106364846796}{\dbinom{457}{5}}\approx 0.654534994130579$$

If getting handfuls of 4 or 5 are equally likely, take average of those two probabilities.

If we require that A being grabbed twice (and at most 2 balls are picked from other types) , change the g.f. to:

$$\displaystyle G_A(x)=\left(\binom{127}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+100\, x+\binom{100}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+61\, x+\binom{61}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+52\, x+\binom{52}{2}\, x^2 \right)\, \left(1+117\, x+\binom{117}{2}\, x^2 \right)$$

and
$$\displaystyle \mathbb{P_A}(\text{4 balls})=\dfrac{[x^4]G_A(x)}{\dbinom{457}{4}}=\dfrac{434334285}{\dbinom{457}{4}}\approx 0.242151443362631$$

$$\displaystyle \mathbb{P_A}(\text{5 balls})=\dfrac{[x^5]G_A(x)}{\dbinom{457}{5}}=\dfrac{43647375240}{\dbinom{457}{5}}\approx 0.268591883099511$$

From your experiment,

$$P=\frac{17}{101}\approx 0.168316831683168$$
which is less than the analytical answers, it's up to you what to do with it!